# Dynamically Changing the Size of an Array

Tags: android

I'm writing a simple GPS program that stores locations in a array of `String` objects. Right now the array is set to 100. When another `String` is added, it creates a new `String` array of 200, copies the old to the new, then sets the variables equal to the new one. Is there a way to just dynamically enlarge the size of an array, without having to create a new array every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way is to use the ArrayList

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you should use the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class. It gives you methods for growing your array dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Try a [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)?

Obviously, you could also use any of the other classes in the [Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html) as well, depending on your requirements.

Comment: `Vector` is pretty much deprecated, `Collections.synchronizedList(ArrayList)` would be the replacement if you really want the synchronized behavior (which is usually not the type of synchronization you actually need).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `ArrayList<String>` and just keep adding to it as you see fit.